# How jdbc polling interval works? and How to add debug logging to a specific jdbc poller inbound adapter?

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to monitor the polling intervals behavior, considering some lag in poller query response and the time taken by the message processing itself.

I have multiple jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter configured. 
How can I put a debugger to know if a specific poller is working or not?
Inbound adapter is configured to poll every 200ms but I see application server intermittently stops polling for few minutes even if there rows in the table.

I tried logging with "org.springframework.integration" but it logs generic SourcePollingChannelAdapter log only and does not show the adapter name/id.

logback.xml:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.integration" level="debug"></logger>
```

This is shown in Logger:

```
2019-08-28 09:48:58 [task-scheduler-5] DEBUG o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter
```

1) How can I know if a specific poller is working or not?

2) What will happen, if a poller is polling every 200 ms but DB takes 300ms to run the query. Will server still keep on requesting every 200ms(upto max thread) or Would it do subsequent polling request 200ms after the response of the last polling request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take some time to investigate a behavior for the poller: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/core.html#channel-adapter-namespace-inbound

In general, there is a `TaskScheduler` used by all the pollers with a `10` thread pool.
So, if you have more than 10 pollers, you need to consider to increase the pool size of that `TaskScheduler`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler

The point of the polling period depends on the option you provide:

- `delay` is about how long to sleep after the previous task has been *finished*
- `rate` - how long to sleep after the previous task has been *start*

Also when you have a thread shift downstream, the task exists a scheduler's thread and you are free to do a new poll cycle.

For logging we recommend to use a `Message History` and global `WireTap`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/system-management.html#message-history

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/core.html#channel-wiretap

Comment: I have only fixed-rate="200" attribute specified in the poller. 
What is the attribute for the delay? 
so in most situations delay would better over rate since it would pull the next message after the last one is processed.

Comment: Thanks Artem, for your brilliant insight as always.     WireTap seems to be for logging, do I have to use Message History? Can you please share some example?

Comment: The message history stores all the components message travels in the headers. So, when you log a message with its headers , you’ll see an info about components you are interested in

Comment: I am passing a pojo instead of Message<?> in my methods parameters across the flow. so nothing much to debug there. however, the only thing I am interested in is **debugging the polling activity**. Since, sometime flow takes a very long pause before fetching the next batch. so wondering if there was some stuck thread of the query took a while to return the resultset?

Comment: As I said: the default pool is `10` if you have more than 10 pollers, it is not a surprise that some of them are in stack. Just because a thread is busy on other pollers. You can add `Advice` into the `poller` for such a logging purpose: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/core.html#conditional-pollers

Comment: I have `2` pollers only.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry not being precise: if you use `fixed-rate="200"` and your process is too long for one batch, it is even easy to eat all the threads with one poller. Fixed rate starts a new task after the previous one has been started, not waiting for its finish, therefore a new thread could be obtained from the pool.

Comment: Are you use that you need to poll DB so frequently?

Comment: yes, it needs to be that frequent. Even this is not able to meet the TPS. Is there a better option? I guess it's okay, if one poller eats all the thread.

Comment: My poller is transactional and it seem it does not allow (advice-chain)two child elements.   <int:poller fixed-delay="100" time-unit="MILLISECONDS">
   <int:transactional />
   <int:advice-chain/>
  </int:poller>

Comment: Yea, you need to use `<tx:advice>` alongside with your custom `Advice` in the `<advice-chain>` instead of `<transactional>`.

Comment: Well, I don't see reason in so frequent poll since your process doesn't keep up with such a demand.

Comment: I got what you are saying,  I can increase the max row but that would increase the processing time too. How about having more threads? instead of default `10` I can have task-executor of with `30` thread

Comment: That's possible, but you still need to keep in mind the CPU throughput, so at some point you are going to harm performance again. The better way would be to have several instances of your service on different machines, so you would distribute the work evenly without loosing performance.

Comment: for sure, have to gauge CPU throughput...thanks. Can you please share some example for the custom `Advice` with for logging?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but  there is a `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` for your consideration to extend with. You need to implement `beforeReceive` or `afterReceive` to log something. You can take a look into existing implementations for inspiration.

Comment: that's what I was looking for Artem...thanks again...it worked.